# Retrieve value from array

Tags: php, arrays

While retrieving values from array without index in PHP I am getting nothing.
From my database value is stored like ["SCHOOL"] and I want to get just SCHOOL from this.
It's not treated as array instead it's treated as a string.
What will be the solution if want to treat this as array and get value of that array.

My Code is as follows :

$stream_arr = $res_tbl['streams'];
which gives result as ["SCHOOL"]

and I want just SCHOOL from this.

I am using code as $stream = $stream_arr[0];
and I get '[' this as result.

If I assign manual value to $stream_arr = ["SCHOOL"],
above code works and returns SCHOOL as expected. 
But for results from my database is not working where result is same as the one I manually assigned.

Comment: Please include more details such as the language you are using and the code that you are using that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate braces from the string you can use below code.

```
$stream_arr = '["SCHOOL"]';
$temp=explode('"',$stream_arr);
$val=$temp[1];
echo $val; //it will dispaly 'SCHOOL'.
```

But check the insert query(from the place you store data into db) that why it is storing with braces? if it is done by you as required then proceed else first fix that issue instead of eliminating braces in php code.

Comment: Thank You! This code is working fine for just a single value.
If value will be like ["SCHOOL", "COLLEGE"] then it won't work and need to solve it in a different way.
My purpose is to define this as an array and not treating as String.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for this in db store as "SCHOOL, COLLEGE" by csv format by eliminating square braces then u can simply use above code by incrementing key values in array.